# divide x no of files equally and remaining add in such a way that it reaches the last set

Tags: sql, bash, shell, unix, sh

```
begin
 for i in 0 .. 50 /* for example where 50 is the maximum file number */
 loop
      insert into abcd_table
      values('abc1405'||ltrim(to_char(i,'009'))||'.jpeg', null, null);
 end loop;
end;
/
```

The above query assign null in all the 50 rows.
(50 is just a no it could be 70 or 45)

I want to put 1 value for the 0-5 rows (fixed)

and all the remaining files to be divided into 6 parts like

```
6-12 as 2    
13-19 as 3
20-26 as 4    
27-33 as 5    
34-40 as 6    
41-47 as 7
```

and as in this case 3 files left then increase 1 each from last set like

```
27-34 as 5    
35-42 as 6    
43-50 as 7
```

so now the sequence is as below:

```
 6-12 as 2    
13-19 as 3    
20-26 as 4    
27-34 as 5    
35-42 as 6    
43-50 as 7
```

Comment: What is your question? What part of this task, specifically, do you need help with?

Comment: I want these different values in 3rd field.

Comment: last generic sequence is my requirement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

/*LOOP 1*/

begin

for i in 0 .. 5  /* files fixed for any no of files */

loop

```
  insert into acd_load_files

  values('acd1405'||ltrim(to_char(i,'009'))||'.rdf', null, 1);
```

end loop;

end;

/

/*Now divide no of remaining files in this case (50-6=44) that they first equally divided 
into 6 loops So there will be

7 files in each loop and remaining 3 files then adjust in such a way that last loop (loop 
7) should have 1 file more or equal to

second last loop (loop 6)  */

so files between loop-2 and loop7  should be ascending order  as below

/*LOOP 2*/

begin

for i in 6 .. 12

loop

```
  insert into acd_load_files

  values('acd1405'||ltrim(to_char(i,'009'))||'.rdf', null, 2);
```

end loop;

end;

/

/*LOOP 3*/

begin

for i in 13 .. 19

loop

```
  insert into acd_load_files

  values('acd1405'||ltrim(to_char(i,'009'))||'.rdf', null, 3);
```

end loop;

end;

/

/*LOOP 4*/

begin

for i in 20 .. 26

loop

```
  insert into acd_load_files

  values('acd1405'||ltrim(to_char(i,'009'))||'.rdf', null, 4);
```

end loop;

end;

/

/*LOOP 5*/

begin

for i in 27 .. 34

loop

```
  insert into acd_load_files

  values('acd1405'||ltrim(to_char(i,'009'))||'.rdf', null, 5);
```

end loop;
end;

/

/*LOOP 6*/

begin

for i in 35 .. 42

loop

```
  insert into acd_load_files
  values('acd1405'||ltrim(to_char(i,'009'))||'.rdf', null, 6);
```

end loop;

end;

/

/*LOOP 7*/
begin

for i in 43 .. 50

loop
      insert into acd_load_files

```
  values('acd1405'||ltrim(to_char(i,'009'))||'.rdf', null, 7);
```

end loop;
end;

/

I need to generic this above code.